# Is it possible [how?] to blacklist & whitelist shell_exec() commands?

Tags: php, shell-exec

I need to **allow** the following:

```
shell_exec('whois ' . $domain);
```

BUT I need to **disallow** everything else, like:

```
shell_exec('ls');
shell_exec('rm -rf /');
shell_exec('sudo service nginx restart');
```

is it possible to "whitelist" only one `shell_exec` command?

Comment: It may be more suitable for [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's about some script — just don't pass user input into `shell_exec` argument, call it when some param matches some value

```
if ($_GET['cmd'] === 'whois') {
    shell_exec('whois whatever');
}
```

If it's about kind of hosting, then you should restrict access to data using OS permissions. So user will be able to call `shell_exec('rm -rf /')` but nothing will happen.

Comment: I guess the per user restriction could work here then. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its not really the answer to your question but:

you can check it with php:

```
if(substr( $command , 0, 5 ) === "whois"){
  shell_exec($command );
}
```

but still i dont think its smart to put user input in shell_exec but if you really want it i should check everthing first with php